# Modify object stored in AsyncLocal

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

There is a statement about [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-5.0) in [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149205450X):

> You should only store immutable data in the AsyncLocal.

At the same time I look into [HttpContextAccessor implementation](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpContextAccessor.cs,a52f908db48fbef3) and I see it's implemented based on `AsyncLocal`. In `ASP.NET Core` application I **can** modify `HttpContext` received from `HttpContextAccessor`  (for instance, I can put some data into `HttpContext.Items` or add a custom header into `HttpContext.Response.Headers`).

What is the problem with modification of an object stored in the `AsyncLocal`? And why it's OK in `HttpContextAccessor` case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the main point is that AsyncLocal can be accessed from different threads (example you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63732530/3231375)).

And recommendation to use immutable data is a common recommended way for such cases.

Comment: That's right, `HttpContext` isn't supposed to be used in parallel (i.e. it's not thread safe), but it's ok to use it in asynchronous flow consequently.